# Calculating minimum distance between two cities with pl/sql

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, backtracking

I need to be able to calculate the minimum distance between two cities given a table that has the distances between pairs of cities. Two cities may not be connected directly, instead they may be connected via a third city and so on.

Here are the tables that I have

```
SQL> desc city
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------

 CITY_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER
 CITY_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(80)
 CITY_STATE                                         VARCHAR2(80)
 ACTIVE                                             CHAR(1)
```

and

```
SQL> desc connection
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------

 CITY1                                     NOT NULL NUMBER
 CITY2                                     NOT NULL NUMBER
 NO_OF_DAYS                                NOT NULL NUMBER
```

I don't know how recursion and backtracking work in pl/sql.

Comment: Why does this seem like something not suited to being done in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try coding [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) in PL/SQL.

Or try [this SQL solution](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/shortest_distance.html).

Comment: Excellent, I was looking for something like the second link that you posted. Many thanks.